# Flutter form data post issue

Tags: android, flutter, dart, post, form-data

I want to send data as FormData to the server but unable to find any way in the Flutter. No doubt flutter supports form data type but how to implement.
Thanks

Comment: By using a `Post` method, and in the headers, specifying that it's a `form` encoded request.

Comment: Do you mean by x-www_form-urlencoded?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 0):

This link can help you

https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html

Or, in one of my projects I used the following code

```
var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", Uri.parse('http://...'));

Map<String, String> headers = {"Authorization": 'Bearer $token'};//<-- create header
request.headers.addAll(headers); // <-- add header    


if (imageFile != null) { //<-- add file (File imageFile)
    var stream = new http.ByteStream(imageFile.openRead());
    var length = await imageFile.length();

    var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('FileUplod', stream, length,
        filename: basename(imageFile.path));
    request.files.add(multipartFile);
}

request.fields['title'] = 'title'; //<--add text item
request.fields['id'] = '12225';

var response = await httpFromData(request);
var responses = await http.Response.fromStream(response);

//json.decode(responses.body)  <-- for decode request body if needed
```